# How to remove a text (without tag) in a label using CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to remove a text (without tag) in a label using CSS selector?

```
<label>
   Email*<br>
   <input class="es_required_field" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required="" />
</label>
```

Comment: <label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required=""></label>

Comment: What text you have to remove? Need more explanation

Comment: Email*   
<label>Email*<br><input class="es_required_field" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required=""></label>

Comment: In your code you have remove the `Email`?

Comment: Any requirements like using Javascript or Jquery?